# How do I access individual items from a list in c#?

Tags: c#, list, loops

I am reading customer's account information from a csv file in a basic banking program. So I am parsing the account data from a csv and converting it into class objects and then putting those objects in a list and I am trying to use a loop to retrieve this data and use it to allow customers to login and carry out transactions.

```
public class Account
{
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string PIN { get; set; }
    public double Balance { get; set; }

    internal static Account ParseRow(string row)
    {
        var columns = row.Split(',');

        return new Account()
        {
            CustomerName = columns[0],
            PIN = columns[1],
            Balance = double.Parse(columns[2])
        };
    }
}

public partial class Form2 : Form 
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private static List<Account> ProcessCSV(string path)
    {
        return System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path)
            .Skip(1)
            .Where(row => row.Length > 0)
            .Select(Account.ParseRow).ToList();
    }

    private void btnLogin_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var accounts = ProcessCSV("Accounts.csv");

        if (txtUsername.Text == "" || txtPassword.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please ensure to fill in all fields");
        }

        foreach (var account in accounts)
        {
            if (txtUsername.Text == account.CustomerName)
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                lblUsername.Text = "Incorrect Username";
            }

            if (txtPassword.Text == account.PIN)
            {
                Form1 f1 = new Form1();
                f1.ShowDialog();
            }
            else
            {
                lblPassword.Text = "Incorrect Password";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It seems the program is picking all the items from the list such as all customer names where `account.CustomerName` is concerned and so on. I just want to pick out and individual customer name and pin to validate the Login of a customer, how can I do this?

Comment: Your foreach loop doesn't make much sense. You should show the form only if _both_ customer name _and_ pin match. You show the next dialog if the customer doesn't match, but the password does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//You can use LINQ to get the first matching account or default (null) if none found
var useraccount = accounts.FirstOrDefault(z => 
                             z.CustomerName == txtUsername.Text && 
                             z.PIN == txtPassword.Text)



if(useraccount != null)
{
    //Do something since it's valid
}
else
{
    //Do something since it's not valid
}
```

Comment: It worked straight away, thanks a lot @Ryan Wilson

Comment: @HermanKapange You're welcome. Have a good day.

Comment: In addition to this, how could I also access these account details in another form, for example displaying in another form, the CustomerName or Balance of a customer who has just logged in. Is it still possible to use LINQ?

Comment: @HermanKapange `LINQ` is usable anywhere in your project as long as you have it referenced. If you wanted to pass account data to another Form, you could do it in multiple ways, one of which would be adding some static properties to your application, another being, using a database, another being adding some properties to this other Form object, as this is a completely different question, you may want to research this more as there should be plenty of information on the subject or if you can't get the information you need, ask a new question.